# probability and expectation without replacement

Tags: random-variables

From a box containing N identical tickets numbered 1 to N, n tickets are drawn without replacement. Let X be the largest number drawn. Find E[X]

I got the pdf as x-1Cn-1/NCn
And E(X)=summation x*pdf
Here i am stuck and i dont know whether what i have done is right or no

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Add this to your question by means of an [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1544103/edit).

Comment: Can you find $P(X\leq k)$ for $k\in\{n,n+1,\dots,N\}$? If so then you can apply my hint.

Comment: Your probability mass function (pmf, not pdf) is not okay. The best way to find it is: $P(X=k)=P(X\leq k)-P(X\leq k-1)$. Actually if you use my hint you don't have to find it. Finding $P(X\leq k)$ is enough then.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $\mathbb EX=P(X\geq1)+\dots+P(X\geq N)$
- $P(X\geq k+1)+P(X\leq k)=1$

---

edit:

$$\mathbb{E}X=\sum_{i=1}^{N}ip_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{i}p_{i}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sum_{i=k}^{N}p_{i}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}P\left(X\geq k\right)=$$$$\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(1-P\left(X\leq k-1\right)\right)=N-\sum_{k=1}^{N}P\left(X\leq k-1\right)=N-\sum_{k=n}^{N-1}P\left(X\leq k\right)$$
and for $k\in\{n,n+1,\dots,N\}$:
$$P(X\leq k)=\frac{\binom{k}{n}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

Comment: Can u plz elaborate your answer

Comment: Do you agree with the first line of it?

Comment: Ya sorry pmf not pdf.i understood that u r calculating max(X1,X2,.....Xn),since it is discrete u r using this method,if it was continuous den u can use order statistics

Comment: Thanxx a ton bro

Comment: You are welcome. You end up with $\mathbb{E}X=N+1-\binom{N}{n}^{-1}\sum_{k=n}^{N}\binom{k}{n}$.
What remains is finding a closed form for $\sum_{k=n}^{N}\binom{k}{n}$.